# Wordpress list of authors

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I get an array or list of users in wordpress? I want to be able to store a new list of authors for permissions for a new plugin I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you an array with users

```
$blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
if ($blogusers) {
foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
$user = get_userdata($bloguser->user_id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Everytime you need to do something in Wordpress, is a good practice to check it's [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page), specially [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) and [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/) references.

[wp_list_authors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_authors) is an example.

> Displays a list of the blog's authors
>   (users), and if the user has authored
>   any posts, the author name is
>   displayed as a link to their posts.
>   Optionally this tag displays each
>   author's post count and RSS feed link.

Since you want to manipulate the values from a template tag, you can use the `echo` parameter set to `0`.

```
<?php $authors_list = wp_list_authors('show_fullname=1&optioncount=1&echo=0');?>
```

Comment: Nvmd This Fails script because it is trying to print a list of authors not give me an array of authors.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/knr-author-list-widget/) plugin selects from the users and usermeta tables. Looking at the source for it might be a good place to start.